# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've researched this error, and it seems like it comes from mere mistakes on behalf of the SQL command. My command looks right to me, but maybe I'm missing something. My full error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'VALUES ('John', 'Doe', '12/19/91', 'N/A', 'Single', 'N/A', 'N/A', 'N/A', '12/10/' at line 1
```

Now my code snippet, any help is greatly appreciated:

```
String DML = "INSERT INTO MEMBERS (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDATE, DEATH_DATE, MARITAL_STATUS, WEDDING_DATE, SPOUSE_NAME, MILITARY_SERVICE, DATE_JOINED, DEPARTURE_DATE, ACCEPTANCE_MODE, DEPARTURE_MODE, RELATED_TO, NOTES VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";


PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(DML);
pstmt.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
pstmt.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
pstmt.setString(3, jTextField6.getText());
pstmt.setString(4, jTextField11.getText());
pstmt.setString(5, jTextField3.getText());
pstmt.setString(6, jTextField5.getText());
pstmt.setString(7, jTextField4.getText());
pstmt.setString(8, jTextField8.getText());
pstmt.setString(9, jTextField7.getText());
pstmt.setString(10, jTextField10.getText());
pstmt.setString(11, jTextField9.getText());
pstmt.setString(12, jTextField13.getText());
pstmt.setString(13, jTextField14.getText());
pstmt.setString(14, jTextArea1.getText());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `)` between `NOTES) VALUES`

```
  INSERT INTO MEMBERS (FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTHDATE, DEATH_DATE, MARITAL_STATUS, WEDDING_DATE, SPOUSE_NAME, MILITARY_SERVICE, DATE_JOINED, DEPARTURE_DATE, ACCEPTANCE_MODE, DEPARTURE_MODE, RELATED_TO, NOTES) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
```